# Skip or Run a Jest Test Based on Variable

Tags: jestjs, automated-tests, puppeteer, e2e-testing, e2e

I am wondering if it is possible in Jest to skip one or more tests in a suite based on the value of a variable used in the beforeEach function.

My code:

```
  let errLoadingData = false;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await page.goto('myurl.com');
    try {
      await waitForSelector('error-banner');
    } catch (error) {
      errLoadingData = true;
      throw new Error(
        'Myurl page displaying error to user.',
      );
    }
  });

  test('Visit myurl page', async () => {
    // wait for and click elements on myurl page
    .
    .
    .
  }
```

I would like to not run `Visit myurl page` if `errLoadingData` = true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Puppeteer is not a test framework. To skip or run a test should be handled by the test framework e.g. Mocha/Jest (whichever you are using).

Comment: @yeniv Thanks, I am using Jest.  Edited post to reflect that.

Comment: Jest provides option to skip tests: [check here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testskipname-fn)

Comment: @yeniv I know about this option; I am asking if there is a way to conditionally skip a test based on a certain variable.  I don't see that here, so I guess it's not possible.